# Python package Kucoin not recognized; no module error

Tags: python, module, pip

I am getting the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin.client'; 'kucoin' is not a package" when running the code underneath. I did pip install like in the documentation here: http://python-kucoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#response-timestamps . What is going wrong?

```
from kucoin.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

# optionally pass the language you would like to use
# see client.get_languages() for options
#client = Client(api_key, api_secret, language='zh_CN)
client.get_languages()
```

Comment: What Python versions do you have installed? What Python versions were used to run `pip install` and to run the script?

Comment: python 3.6.3 and I just use idle of python which states its the same version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saved a python file as kucoin.py . That interfered with loading the module

Comment: Well that was an annoying error!